# Issue in StyleCop Custom Rules integration in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I wish to use StyleCop to frame my custom rule set. I downloaded a latest version of [SytleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) and I followed the implementation procedure from one of the [Blog](http://www.developerin.net/a/66-StyleCop/50-Create-custom-rules-using-StyleCop).

I Implemented as identical to the above said Blog.

```
Project -> Right Click -> StyleCop Settings
```

[image]

It opens the StyleCop Setting Dialogue Window using **`StyleCop 5.0 (build 5.0.6187.1)`**

[image]

In the above window I can't able to see my Custom Rule. I opened the file explorer and navigate to the respective project's file path, there I noticed **`Settings.StyleCop`**

[image]

I tried to open the **`Settings.StyleCop`** by double click, it's opened the Settings file using **`StyleCop 4.7 (4.7.55.0)`**

[image]

Kindly assist me how to Create a Custom Rule and how to apply the rule in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un-Install any extension you installed via Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> StyleCop

[image]

Moreover Re-Install the [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (i.e., Un-Install and again Install) because some of the dll won't be remove of the above said Extensions file.

Comment: Hi This solution is not working in Visual studio 15 can any one help me on this?